# Как правильно составить запрос MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите как правильно составить вот такой запрос.

Есть две таблицы. Продукты: `id`, `product_title`, `category_id`  Мне нужен такой запрос, что бы сначала выбрал все продукты у которых `category_id == от 1 до 7`, а потом от 8 и до конца.

`Select * from product_id where category_id>=1 and category_id<=7`

(а дальше не понимаю). Нужно что бы выдавал все в одном запросе!

Comment: В данном случае, если `category_id` никогда не равен 0 и всегда положителен, то вам подойдет `ORDER BY category_id ASC` безо всяких условий. Это называется сортировкой.

Comment: Или вас интересовало как вывести данные из двух таблиц через один запрос? Тогда `join` делать надо: `SELECT * FROM product LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = product.category_id`. Вместо `LEFT` можно использовать `INNER` или `RIGHT` (зависит от целей).

Comment: Спасибо помог первый способ

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментариев:

В данном случае, если `category_id` никогда не равен 0 и всегда положителен, то вам подойдет `ORDER BY category_id ASC` безо всяких условий. Это называется сортировкой.

Или вас интересовало как вывести данные из двух таблиц через один запрос? Тогда join делать надо: `SELECT * FROM product LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = product.category_id`. Вместо `LEFT` можно использовать `INNER` или `RIGHT` (зависит от целей).

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "а потом от 8 и до конца" и "все в одном запросе"?

Если нужно получить все записи, то это нужно делать без каких-либо category_id>=1 and category_id<=7
А группировать, или что вам нужно, уже полученные данные на сервере